# Creating objects dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, oop

In `index.php` I'm calling `Engine::router()` method (located in `app/Engine.php`) to get from request a string, for instance `'home'` and put them to `$controller`. Then I want to create new object using this string.

```
$className = $controler.'Controller';
```

Then i'm trying to create a object from class names `homeController`, located in `controllers/homeController.php` directory.

```
require 'controllers/'.$className.'.php';
$CONTROLLER = new $className();
```

but i still get `Fatal error: Class 'homeController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\w8\app\Engine.php on line 67`

**Important!** When I replace `$className` by 'homeController' (not a string) then object is created properly.

```
$CONTROLLER = new homeController();
```

Full code of app/Engine.php (class Engine)

```
public static function router()
    {
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        $requestElements = explode('/', $path);

        $requestController = $requestElements[0];
        $availableControllers = self::getControllers();

        if (self::checkController($requestController, $availableControllers))
        {
            $className = $requestController.'Controller';
            require 'controllers/'.$className.'.php';
            $CONTROLLER = new $className();
        }
    }
```

I'm using namespaces following:

**root:**
`index.php (use app\Engine;)`

**directory app:**
`Engine.php (namespace app; use controllers\homeController;)`

**directory controllers:**
`homeController.php (namespace controllers;)`

Additional question: why when I'm unsing in Engine.php `use controllers;` instead `use controllers\homeController;` then I'm getting `Fatal error: Class 'app\homeController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\w8\app\Engine.php on line 67`

Line 67 is `$CONTROLLER = new $className();` or `$CONTROLLER = new homeController();` for both cases.

Comment: Tip: use a PSR-4 autoloader (like Composer) rather than requiring your files manually

Comment: Thanks for tip but I can't use it (projects requirements)

Comment: Generally PHP has an awesome feature called autoloading(http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) which should ideally prevent require or require_once from needing to be used ever again.